# postfix system "mail name"

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I am installing postfix and I am confused what to put for the system mail name. It has an exmaple that sais use "example.org" if a mail address on the system is "foo@example.org" but it also sais that the mail name should be the FQDN.

my hostname is "mercury" and my FQDN is "mercury.pacificseatheat.org", so should I use "pacificseatheat.org" or "mercury.pacificseatheat.org" for the system mail name?

Thanks

Comment: What's the specific parameter you're trying to set in main.cf?

Comment: I am in the process of installing postfix. This is the mail name setting in the package configuration window during installation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would depend how your mail is set up. Generally pacificseatheat.org sounds better, as in most cases, organizations use this format regardless of the actual server sending the mail. However, using the longer one will work as well.

You can always change that later in /etc/mailname.

Comment: Are you saying the name is arbitrary (with regard to ability to send) and that mail will still send no matter what it is?